# how to show a zoomable image in a windows 8 (WinRT) app?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is it possible to put a image into a control in WinRT and then let the user zoom in and out etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

The easiest possible way is to put it inside a scrollviewer. You can zoom in and out whatever you like that way!

```
<ScrollViewer MaxZoomFactor="3"
              MinZoomFactor="0.5"
              ZoomMode="Enabled">
    <Image Source="/Assets/logo.png" Width="200" Height="200"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```